# Regex is not matching all occurrences

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am trying to match all occurrences  `<% anything %>` inside a template literal.
My regex setup looks like this.

```
process(template : string , data: Object) {
    let re = /<%([^%>]+)?%>/g, match;
    while (match = re.exec(template)) {
        template = template.replace(match[0], data[match[1]]);
    }
    return template;
}
```

if my template looks like this

```
`<div class="tile">
        <span><%ENTRY_NUMBER%></span> 
        <span><%NAME%> , <%CLASS%> , <%GENDER%> , <%AGE%></span>
</div>`
```

it will match the first occurrence just fine then keep picking the alternate occurrences. if there is one match inside a html tag it works fine but when i use multiples like in second span element it misses alternate occurrences. I think it has something to do with < and >.

When I separate those occurrences with `<>` instead of comma like below it works fine.

```
<span><%NAME%> <> <%CLASS%> <> <%GENDER%> <> <%AGE%></span>
```

The result it like this

```
<span> john <> biology <> male <> 17 </span>
```

I have examined the regex multiple times but to no avail.

Comment: Try replacing your `while` block with `return template.replace(re, function($0, $1) { return data[$1] ? data[$1] : $0; })`. Also, I would use `let re = /<%(.+?)%>/g` as the regex here (just in case there is `>` or `%` in the data keys).

Comment: Thanks for the help but I am looking for an explanation **why** my code does not work. Also i have never seen var names with $ in js.

Comment: JavaScript treats `$` and `_` as letters when they are used in names; there is nothing else special about them. Both are actually quite common in JavaScript code: `$` in jQuery code, and `_` in Underscore/Lodash code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `re.lastIndex` stores the value that is correct for the previous value of `template`, but since you change the `template` value the `re.lastIndex` is no longer correct for the modified string.

See a simplified example below:

```js
let template = `<%ENTRY_NUMBER%><%NAME%><%CLASS%><%GENDER%><%AGE%>`;
let re = /<%(.+?)%>/g, match;
let data = { 'NAME':'John', 'CLASS':'A3', 'GENDER':'Male', 'AGE':'19' };
while (match = re.exec(template)) {
    console.log(re.lastIndex);
    template = template.replace(match[0], data[match[1]]);
    console.log(template);
}
console.log(template);

// Iteration 1: re.lastIndex = 16
// undefined<%NAME%><%CLASS%><%GENDER%><%AGE%>
// Index is now between <%NAME% and > -> this match will be skipped
// and so on...
```

Thus, it is better to modify the string on the fly inside a replace callback since all matches will get replaced once they are found, and you won't have to track the indices where to search from.

Use

```
process(template : string , data: Object) {
    return template.replace(/<%(.+?)%>/g, function($0, $1) { 
              return data[$1] ? data[$1] : $0; 
           });
}
```

Note that `<%(.+?)%>` matches `<%`, then captures any 1 or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible into Group 1 and then matches `%>`. This way, you will also match values that contain `%` and `>` (it is important if `data` contains such keys).

Comment: The problem with his approach is the `g` flag which brings in the `lastIndex` issue you have highlighted. Using the `m` flag instead will make his approach work just fine.  And yeah, the replace with a callback is more elegant :)

Comment: Yes, I already mentioned the `re.lastIndex` is modified upon each match. Look: [*If your regular expression uses the "g" flag, you can use the `exec()` method multiple times to find successive matches in the same string. When you do so, the search starts at the substring of `str` specified by the regular expression's `lastIndex` property (`test()` will also advance the `lastIndex` property)*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec). `m` flag is totally redundant here.

Comment: Just saying that removing the g flag from his initial source will solve the problem.

Comment: @bluehipy I agree, but it will solve the problem in an inefficient way. Why matching the same text twice?

Comment: I already said that the replace with a callback is more elegant :)  Why match twice or multiple times the same text? because javascript will not return all the matches at once, using exec :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you don't need a global flag `g` becuase you reexecute the expression over and over until will not match but a multiline flag `m`

```js
let s = `<div class="tile">
        <span><%ENTRY_NUMBER%></span> 
        <span><%NAME%> , <%CLASS%> , <%GENDER%> , <%AGE%></span>
</div>`;
const re = /<%([^\%]+)?%>/,
  data = {
    ENTRY_NUMBER: '1977',
    NAME: 'Blue',
    CLASS: 'Vertebrates',
    GENDER: 'Male',
    AGE: '40'
  };


let k = 0;
while (re.test(s) && k++ < 1000) {
  match = re.exec(s);
  if (match) s = s.replace(match[0], data[match[1]]);
}
console.log(s);
```

Comment: Do you know what `m` modifier does? Hint: if you remove it from your pattern, the results will be the same. Do you know that `<`, `%`, and `>` are not special regex metacharacters and do not need escaping?